# JAVA setVisible does not hide the component

Tags: java, swing

i'm trying to hide all jLists except for 1 which i get from the index of the jcomboBox (cbLists),
It doesn't really hide the jLists it's like disabled not hidden, I need it to hide all like completely invisible except for 1 this is the code i'm attempting:

```
package javaapplication2;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class Form1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Form1() {
        initComponents();

        ActionListener actionListener = (ActionEvent e) -> {
            System.out.println("Selected: " + cbLists.getSelectedItem());
            System.out.println(", Position: " + cbLists.getSelectedIndex());
            setCB(cbLists.getSelectedIndex());
        };
        cbLists.addActionListener(actionListener);
    }

    private void setCB(int index) {
        switch (index) {
            case 1:
                jList1.setVisible(false);
                jList4.setVisible(false);
                jList3.setVisible(false);
                jList2.setVisible(true);
                break;
            case 2:
                jList1.setVisible(false);
                jList2.setVisible(false);
                jList3.setVisible(true);
                jList4.setVisible(false);
                break;
            case 3:
                jList1.setVisible(false);
                jList2.setVisible(false);
                jList3.setVisible(false);
                jList4.setVisible(true);
                break;
            default:
                jList1.setVisible(true);
                jList2.setVisible(false);
                jList3.setVisible(false);
                jList4.setVisible(false);
                break;
        }

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        cbLists = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jList1 = new javax.swing.JList<>();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jList2 = new javax.swing.JList<>();
        jScrollPane3 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jList3 = new javax.swing.JList<>();
        jScrollPane4 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jList4 = new javax.swing.JList<>();

        cbLists.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "jList1", "jList2", "jList3", "jList4" }));

        jList1.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>() {
            String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
            public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
            public String getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jList1);

        jList2.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>() {
            String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
            public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
            public String getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
        });
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jList2);

        jList3.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>() {
            String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
            public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
            public String getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
        });
        jScrollPane3.setViewportView(jList3);

        jList4.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>() {
            String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
            public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
            public String getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
        });
        jScrollPane4.setViewportView(jList4);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 248, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(cbLists, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(622, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(25, 25, 25)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 248, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(612, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 248, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(602, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(45, 45, 45)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 248, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(592, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 266, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(cbLists, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(143, 143, 143))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 266, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGap(168, 168, 168)))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 266, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGap(158, 158, 158)))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(46, 46, 46)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 266, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGap(148, 148, 148)))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Form1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new Form1().setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> cbLists;
    private javax.swing.JList<String> jList1;
    private javax.swing.JList<String> jList2;
    private javax.swing.JList<String> jList3;
    private javax.swing.JList<String> jList4;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane3;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane4;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

As you can see in the image jList2 is selected its behind jList1 i need it to be in the front and the rest invisible it's weird...

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to hide your jScrollPane1 - jScrollPane4.
So the grey boxes you are seeing are the JScrollPanes. They are not disabled, they are just empty because you have hidden the white List in it. You have to hide the whole panes.

You can improve your code a bit if you want... for example you can create a List of Scrollpanes

```
private List<JScrollPane> scrollPaneList = new ArrayList<>();
```

and add your panes to the list

```
this.scrollPaneList.addAll(Arrays.asList(jScrollPane1, jScrollPane2, jScrollPane3, jScrollPane4));
```

and then you can do someting like this

```
    private void setCB(int index)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < scrollPaneList.size(); i++)
        {
            scrollPaneList.get(i).setVisible(index == i);
        }      

    }
```